# Error message: skipping unreadable file & no usable data in this plot to auto-scale axis range & all points x value undefined

Tags: java, gnuplot

Help, i just got into gnuplot, and was trying to plot a surface generated using java application .what i typed looks like this :

```
     terminal type set to 'windows'
     gnuplot> splot"potentialsurface03"
     warning: Skipping unreadable file "potentialsurface03"
     warning: No usable data in this plot to auto-scale axis range 

     All points x value undefined
```

and this was my data

```js
x = 0.000 y = 120000.000 19826260.654
x = 6000.000 y = 120000.000 20349309.589
x = 12000.000 y = 120000.000 20851872.153
x = 18000.000 y = 120000.000 21326388.404
x = 24000.000 y = 120000.000 21765204.193
x = 30000.000 y = 120000.000 22161476.039
x = 36000.000 y = 120000.000 22510559.269
x = 42000.000 y = 120000.000 22811858.229
x = 48000.000 y = 120000.000 23070970.784
x = 54000.000 y = 120000.000 23301821.611
x = 60000.000 y = 120000.000 23528380.908
x = 66000.000 y = 120000.000 23785357.227
x = 72000.000 y = 120000.000 24116286.066
x = 78000.000 y = 120000.000 24563962.339
x = 84000.000 y = 120000.000 25139073.420
x = 90000.000 y = 120000.000 25741941.800
x = 96000.000 y = 120000.000 26057277.656
x = 102000.000 y = 120000.000 25652256.422
x = 108000.000 y = 120000.000 24441846.786
x = 114000.000 y = 120000.000 22815899.846
x = 120000.000 y = 120000.000 21177183.079

x = 0.000 y = 114000.000 20894889.957
x = 6000.000 y = 114000.000 21501411.342
x = 12000.000 y = 114000.000 22088146.663
x = 18000.000 y = 114000.000 22645216.059
x = 24000.000 y = 114000.000 23161884.758
x = 30000.000 y = 114000.000 23627644.963
x = 36000.000 y = 114000.000 24034170.722
x = 42000.000 y = 114000.000 24378242.584
x = 48000.000 y = 114000.000 24665488.895
x = 54000.000 y = 114000.000 24914594.668
x = 60000.000 y = 114000.000 25161745.209
x = 66000.000 y = 114000.000 25465627.820
x = 72000.000 y = 114000.000 25913824.685
x = 78000.000 y = 114000.000 26629251.000
x = 84000.000 y = 114000.000 27758314.220
x = 90000.000 y = 114000.000 29343473.818
x = 96000.000 y = 114000.000 30813968.268
x = 102000.000 y = 114000.000 30581928.477
x = 108000.000 y = 114000.000 28216702.168
x = 114000.000 y = 114000.000 25307676.076
x = 120000.000 y = 114000.000 22815899.846

x = 0.000 y = 108000.000 22065812.711
x = 6000.000 y = 108000.000 22773771.758
x = 12000.000 y = 108000.000 23464669.954
x = 18000.000 y = 108000.000 24125787.763
x = 24000.000 y = 108000.000 24742096.615
x = 30000.000 y = 108000.000 25297292.222
x = 36000.000 y = 108000.000 25776308.191
x = 42000.000 y = 108000.000 26169698.002
x = 48000.000 y = 108000.000 26479762.011
x = 54000.000 y = 108000.000 26727780.444
x = 60000.000 y = 108000.000 26961991.694
x = 66000.000 y = 108000.000 27268029.679
x = 72000.000 y = 108000.000 27788495.391
x = 78000.000 y = 108000.000 28768682.791
x = 84000.000 y = 108000.000 30666194.647
x = 90000.000 y = 108000.000 34346347.578
x = 96000.000 y = 108000.000 40335724.243
x = 102000.000 y = 108000.000 41485524.928
x = 108000.000 y = 108000.000 34183889.784
x = 114000.000 y = 108000.000 28216702.168
x = 120000.000 y = 108000.000 24441846.786

x = 0.000 y = 102000.000 23351100.207
x = 6000.000 y = 102000.000 24183060.392
x = 12000.000 y = 102000.000 25004298.673
x = 18000.000 y = 102000.000 25799068.603
x = 24000.000 y = 102000.000 26546818.965
x = 30000.000 y = 102000.000 27222560.765
x = 36000.000 y = 102000.000 27799604.211
x = 42000.000 y = 102000.000 28255824.829
x = 48000.000 y = 102000.000 28583546.510
x = 54000.000 y = 102000.000 28801455.499
x = 60000.000 y = 102000.000 28966562.084
x = 66000.000 y = 102000.000 29187839.726
x = 72000.000 y = 102000.000 29653685.362
x = 78000.000 y = 102000.000 30712726.885
x = 84000.000 y = 102000.000 33152339.331
x = 90000.000 y = 102000.000 39445865.380
x = 96000.000 y = 102000.000 63674577.728
x = 102000.000 y = 102000.000 88816489.502
x = 108000.000 y = 102000.000 41485524.928
x = 114000.000 y = 102000.000 30581928.477
x = 120000.000 y = 102000.000 25652256.422

x = 0.000 y = 96000.000 24763403.028
x = 6000.000 y = 96000.000 25747308.814
x = 12000.000 y = 96000.000 26732853.595
x = 18000.000 y = 96000.000 27702044.226
x = 24000.000 y = 96000.000 28628242.316
x = 30000.000 y = 96000.000 29474406.767
x = 36000.000 y = 96000.000 30194756.510
x = 42000.000 y = 96000.000 30743093.436
x = 48000.000 y = 96000.000 31089167.795
x = 54000.000 y = 96000.000 31239505.703
x = 60000.000 y = 96000.000 31255113.748
x = 66000.000 y = 96000.000 31262703.877
x = 72000.000 y = 96000.000 31471458.853
x = 78000.000 y = 96000.000 32235339.379
x = 84000.000 y = 96000.000 34280463.270
x = 90000.000 y = 96000.000 39603696.398
x = 96000.000 y = 96000.000 55322979.024
x = 102000.000 y = 96000.000 63674577.728
x = 108000.000 y = 96000.000 40335724.243
x = 114000.000 y = 96000.000 30813968.268
x = 120000.000 y = 96000.000 26057277.656

x = 0.000 y = 90000.000 26315443.395
x = 6000.000 y = 90000.000 27485022.692
x = 12000.000 y = 90000.000 28677933.537
x = 18000.000 y = 90000.000 29876894.106
x = 24000.000 y = 90000.000 31050996.177
x = 30000.000 y = 90000.000 32148736.033
x = 36000.000 y = 90000.000 33094624.785
x = 42000.000 y = 90000.000 33797881.870
x = 48000.000 y = 90000.000 34180482.171
x = 54000.000 y = 90000.000 34218833.253
x = 60000.000 y = 90000.000 33975905.891
x = 66000.000 y = 90000.000 33603524.402
x = 72000.000 y = 90000.000 33324394.429
x = 78000.000 y = 90000.000 33428609.812
x = 84000.000 y = 90000.000 34311360.242
x = 90000.000 y = 90000.000 36471191.160
x = 96000.000 y = 90000.000 39603696.398
x = 102000.000 y = 90000.000 39445865.380
x = 108000.000 y = 90000.000 34346347.578
x = 114000.000 y = 90000.000 29343473.818
x = 120000.000 y = 90000.000 25741941.800

x = 0.000 y = 84000.000 28019549.163
x = 6000.000 y = 84000.000 29413881.406
x = 12000.000 y = 84000.000 30866405.158
x = 18000.000 y = 84000.000 32367667.371
x = 24000.000 y = 84000.000 33890506.341
x = 30000.000 y = 84000.000 35372341.849
x = 36000.000 y = 84000.000 36696018.375
x = 42000.000 y = 84000.000 37688743.992
x = 48000.000 y = 84000.000 38168705.718
x = 54000.000 y = 84000.000 38041245.058
x = 60000.000 y = 84000.000 37378299.318
x = 66000.000 y = 84000.000 36403027.458
x = 72000.000 y = 84000.000 35398477.886
x = 78000.000 y = 84000.000 34624026.834
x = 84000.000 y = 84000.000 34262783.909
x = 90000.000 y = 84000.000 34311360.242
x = 96000.000 y = 84000.000 34280463.270
x = 102000.000 y = 84000.000 33152339.331
x = 108000.000 y = 84000.000 30666194.647
x = 114000.000 y = 84000.000 27758314.220
x = 120000.000 y = 84000.000 25139073.420

x = 0.000 y = 78000.000 29887773.362
x = 6000.000 y = 78000.000 31549562.790
x = 12000.000 y = 78000.000 33320454.217
x = 18000.000 y = 78000.000 35212490.355
x = 24000.000 y = 78000.000 37223673.383
x = 30000.000 y = 78000.000 39303132.564
x = 36000.000 y = 78000.000 41292079.601
x = 42000.000 y = 78000.000 42871552.531
x = 48000.000 y = 78000.000 43617420.419
x = 54000.000 y = 78000.000 43246160.263
x = 60000.000 y = 78000.000 41868346.815
x = 66000.000 y = 78000.000 39925491.669
x = 72000.000 y = 78000.000 37893940.272
x = 78000.000 y = 78000.000 36087681.198
x = 84000.000 y = 78000.000 34624026.834
x = 90000.000 y = 78000.000 33428609.812
x = 96000.000 y = 78000.000 32235339.379
x = 102000.000 y = 78000.000 30712726.885
x = 108000.000 y = 78000.000 28768682.791
x = 114000.000 y = 78000.000 26629251.000
x = 120000.000 y = 78000.000 24563962.339

x = 0.000 y = 72000.000 31933712.779
x = 6000.000 y = 72000.000 33906397.885
x = 12000.000 y = 72000.000 36053663.481
x = 18000.000 y = 72000.000 38429795.317
x = 24000.000 y = 72000.000 41102453.217
x = 30000.000 y = 72000.000 44105980.289
x = 36000.000 y = 72000.000 47308610.590
x = 42000.000 y = 72000.000 50175181.489
x = 48000.000 y = 72000.000 51669928.700
x = 54000.000 y = 72000.000 50899888.265
x = 60000.000 y = 72000.000 48124507.053
x = 66000.000 y = 72000.000 44485531.471
x = 72000.000 y = 72000.000 40938521.027
x = 78000.000 y = 72000.000 37893940.272
x = 84000.000 y = 72000.000 35398477.886
x = 90000.000 y = 72000.000 33324394.429
x = 96000.000 y = 72000.000 31471458.853
x = 102000.000 y = 72000.000 29653685.362
x = 108000.000 y = 72000.000 27788495.391
x = 114000.000 y = 72000.000 25913824.685
x = 120000.000 y = 72000.000 24116286.066

x = 0.000 y = 66000.000 34177763.559
x = 6000.000 y = 66000.000 36503601.927
x = 12000.000 y = 66000.000 39072859.995
x = 18000.000 y = 66000.000 42002554.814
x = 24000.000 y = 66000.000 45498827.294
x = 30000.000 y = 66000.000 49852619.922
x = 36000.000 y = 66000.000 55275112.000
x = 42000.000 y = 66000.000 61220419.530
x = 48000.000 y = 66000.000 65095672.289
x = 54000.000 y = 66000.000 63471453.881
x = 60000.000 y = 66000.000 57305690.185
x = 66000.000 y = 66000.000 50351625.184
x = 72000.000 y = 66000.000 44485531.471
x = 78000.000 y = 66000.000 39925491.669
x = 84000.000 y = 66000.000 36403027.458
x = 90000.000 y = 66000.000 33603524.402
x = 96000.000 y = 66000.000 31262703.877
x = 102000.000 y = 66000.000 29187839.726
x = 108000.000 y = 66000.000 27268029.679
x = 114000.000 y = 66000.000 25465627.820
x = 120000.000 y = 66000.000 23785357.227

x = 0.000 y = 60000.000 36657581.022
x = 6000.000 y = 60000.000 39383135.045
x = 12000.000 y = 60000.000 42399349.391
x = 18000.000 y = 60000.000 45882551.407
x = 24000.000 y = 60000.000 50233484.975
x = 30000.000 y = 60000.000 56255664.850
x = 36000.000 y = 60000.000 65372566.378
x = 42000.000 y = 60000.000 79148358.664
x = 48000.000 y = 60000.000 92875863.018
x = 54000.000 y = 60000.000 88141820.048
x = 60000.000 y = 60000.000 71053100.470
x = 66000.000 y = 60000.000 57305690.185
x = 72000.000 y = 60000.000 48124507.053
x = 78000.000 y = 60000.000 41868346.815
x = 84000.000 y = 60000.000 37378299.318
x = 90000.000 y = 60000.000 33975905.891
x = 96000.000 y = 60000.000 31255113.748
x = 102000.000 y = 60000.000 28966562.084
x = 108000.000 y = 60000.000 26961991.694
x = 114000.000 y = 60000.000 25161745.209
x = 120000.000 y = 60000.000 23528380.908

x = 0.000 y = 54000.000 39443591.760
x = 6000.000 y = 54000.000 42645485.184
x = 12000.000 y = 54000.000 46131370.602
x = 18000.000 y = 54000.000 50068504.487
x = 24000.000 y = 54000.000 54998238.852
x = 30000.000 y = 54000.000 62315588.670
x = 36000.000 y = 54000.000 75581735.151
x = 42000.000 y = 54000.000 105887674.973
x = 48000.000 y = 54000.000 186582526.455
x = 54000.000 y = 54000.000 150914089.220
x = 60000.000 y = 54000.000 88141820.048
x = 66000.000 y = 54000.000 63471453.881
x = 72000.000 y = 54000.000 50899888.265
x = 78000.000 y = 54000.000 43246160.263
x = 84000.000 y = 54000.000 38041245.058
x = 90000.000 y = 54000.000 34218833.253
x = 96000.000 y = 54000.000 31239505.703
x = 102000.000 y = 54000.000 28801455.499
x = 108000.000 y = 54000.000 26727780.444
x = 114000.000 y = 54000.000 24914594.668
x = 120000.000 y = 54000.000 23301821.611

x = 0.000 y = 48000.000 42653517.292
x = 6000.000 y = 48000.000 46504195.328
x = 12000.000 y = 48000.000 50570528.488
x = 18000.000 y = 48000.000 54827978.521
x = 24000.000 y = 48000.000 59698941.640
x = 30000.000 y = 48000.000 66738439.677
x = 36000.000 y = 48000.000 80217042.600
x = 42000.000 y = 48000.000 115245735.790
x = 48000.000 y = 48000.000 283755240.899
x = 54000.000 y = 48000.000 186582526.455
x = 60000.000 y = 48000.000 92875863.018
x = 66000.000 y = 48000.000 65095672.289
x = 72000.000 y = 48000.000 51669928.700
x = 78000.000 y = 48000.000 43617420.419
x = 84000.000 y = 48000.000 38168705.718
x = 90000.000 y = 48000.000 34180482.171
x = 96000.000 y = 48000.000 31089167.795
x = 102000.000 y = 48000.000 28583546.510
x = 108000.000 y = 48000.000 26479762.011
x = 114000.000 y = 48000.000 24665488.895
x = 120000.000 y = 48000.000 23070970.784

x = 0.000 y = 42000.000 46446801.595
x = 6000.000 y = 42000.000 51344053.014
x = 12000.000 y = 42000.000 56437029.367
x = 18000.000 y = 42000.000 61121531.255
x = 24000.000 y = 42000.000 65152927.510
x = 30000.000 y = 42000.000 69751113.819
x = 36000.000 y = 42000.000 77899665.293
x = 42000.000 y = 42000.000 93987121.795
x = 48000.000 y = 42000.000 115245735.790
x = 54000.000 y = 42000.000 105887674.973
x = 60000.000 y = 42000.000 79148358.664
x = 66000.000 y = 42000.000 61220419.530
x = 72000.000 y = 42000.000 50175181.489
x = 78000.000 y = 42000.000 42871552.531
x = 84000.000 y = 42000.000 37688743.992
x = 90000.000 y = 42000.000 33797881.870
x = 96000.000 y = 42000.000 30743093.436
x = 102000.000 y = 42000.000 28255824.829
x = 108000.000 y = 42000.000 26169698.002
x = 114000.000 y = 42000.000 24378242.584
x = 120000.000 y = 42000.000 22811858.229

x = 0.000 y = 36000.000 50954258.363
x = 6000.000 y = 36000.000 57714359.227
x = 12000.000 y = 36000.000 65250948.871
x = 18000.000 y = 36000.000 71539098.515
x = 24000.000 y = 36000.000 73947051.168
x = 30000.000 y = 36000.000 73750492.702
x = 36000.000 y = 36000.000 74642080.635
x = 42000.000 y = 36000.000 77899665.293
x = 48000.000 y = 36000.000 80217042.600
x = 54000.000 y = 36000.000 75581735.151
x = 60000.000 y = 36000.000 65372566.378
x = 66000.000 y = 36000.000 55275112.000
x = 72000.000 y = 36000.000 47308610.590
x = 78000.000 y = 36000.000 41292079.601
x = 84000.000 y = 36000.000 36696018.375
x = 90000.000 y = 36000.000 33094624.785
x = 96000.000 y = 36000.000 30194756.510
x = 102000.000 y = 36000.000 27799604.211
x = 108000.000 y = 36000.000 25776308.191
x = 114000.000 y = 36000.000 24034170.722
x = 120000.000 y = 36000.000 22510559.269

x = 0.000 y = 30000.000 56077317.023
x = 6000.000 y = 30000.000 65956382.432
x = 12000.000 y = 30000.000 79941281.298
x = 18000.000 y = 30000.000 94152155.363
x = 24000.000 y = 30000.000 92900880.591
x = 30000.000 y = 30000.000 81607988.270
x = 36000.000 y = 30000.000 73750492.702
x = 42000.000 y = 30000.000 69751113.819
x = 48000.000 y = 30000.000 66738439.677
x = 54000.000 y = 30000.000 62315588.670
x = 60000.000 y = 30000.000 56255664.850
x = 66000.000 y = 30000.000 49852619.922
x = 72000.000 y = 30000.000 44105980.289
x = 78000.000 y = 30000.000 39303132.564
x = 84000.000 y = 30000.000 35372341.849
x = 90000.000 y = 30000.000 32148736.033
x = 96000.000 y = 30000.000 29474406.767
x = 102000.000 y = 30000.000 27222560.765
x = 108000.000 y = 30000.000 25297292.222
x = 114000.000 y = 30000.000 23627644.963
x = 120000.000 y = 30000.000 22161476.039

x = 0.000 y = 24000.000 61270265.934
x = 6000.000 y = 24000.000 74662787.246
x = 12000.000 y = 24000.000 102466416.380
x = 18000.000 y = 24000.000 173801838.277
x = 24000.000 y = 24000.000 144900381.958
x = 30000.000 y = 24000.000 92900880.591
x = 36000.000 y = 24000.000 73947051.168
x = 42000.000 y = 24000.000 65152927.510
x = 48000.000 y = 24000.000 59698941.640
x = 54000.000 y = 24000.000 54998238.852
x = 60000.000 y = 24000.000 50233484.975
x = 66000.000 y = 24000.000 45498827.294
x = 72000.000 y = 24000.000 41102453.217
x = 78000.000 y = 24000.000 37223673.383
x = 84000.000 y = 24000.000 33890506.341
x = 90000.000 y = 24000.000 31050996.177
x = 96000.000 y = 24000.000 28628242.316
x = 102000.000 y = 24000.000 26546818.965
x = 108000.000 y = 24000.000 24742096.615
x = 114000.000 y = 24000.000 23161884.758
x = 120000.000 y = 24000.000 21765204.193

x = 0.000 y = 18000.000 66212943.818
x = 6000.000 y = 18000.000 79617661.955
x = 12000.000 y = 18000.000 110589437.158
x = 18000.000 y = 18000.000 256755933.523
x = 24000.000 y = 18000.000 173801838.277
x = 30000.000 y = 18000.000 94152155.363
x = 36000.000 y = 18000.000 71539098.515
x = 42000.000 y = 18000.000 61121531.255
x = 48000.000 y = 18000.000 54827978.521
x = 54000.000 y = 18000.000 50068504.487
x = 60000.000 y = 18000.000 45882551.407
x = 66000.000 y = 18000.000 42002554.814
x = 72000.000 y = 18000.000 38429795.317
x = 78000.000 y = 18000.000 35212490.355
x = 84000.000 y = 18000.000 32367667.371
x = 90000.000 y = 18000.000 29876894.106
x = 96000.000 y = 18000.000 27702044.226
x = 102000.000 y = 18000.000 25799068.603
x = 108000.000 y = 18000.000 24125787.763
x = 114000.000 y = 18000.000 22645216.059
x = 120000.000 y = 18000.000 21326388.404

x = 0.000 y = 12000.000 73761352.315
x = 6000.000 y = 12000.000 81348451.169
x = 12000.000 y = 12000.000 93319715.274
x = 18000.000 y = 12000.000 110589437.158
x = 24000.000 y = 12000.000 102466416.380
x = 30000.000 y = 12000.000 79941281.298
x = 36000.000 y = 12000.000 65250948.871
x = 42000.000 y = 12000.000 56437029.367
x = 48000.000 y = 12000.000 50570528.488
x = 54000.000 y = 12000.000 46131370.602
x = 60000.000 y = 12000.000 42399349.391
x = 66000.000 y = 12000.000 39072859.995
x = 72000.000 y = 12000.000 36053663.481
x = 78000.000 y = 12000.000 33320454.217
x = 84000.000 y = 12000.000 30866405.158
x = 90000.000 y = 12000.000 28677933.537
x = 96000.000 y = 12000.000 26732853.595
x = 102000.000 y = 12000.000 25004298.673
x = 108000.000 y = 12000.000 23464669.954
x = 114000.000 y = 12000.000 22088146.663
x = 120000.000 y = 12000.000 20851872.153

x = 0.000 y = 6000.000 100727887.297
x = 6000.000 y = 6000.000 89360326.457
x = 12000.000 y = 6000.000 81348451.169
x = 18000.000 y = 6000.000 79617661.955
x = 24000.000 y = 6000.000 74662787.246
x = 30000.000 y = 6000.000 65956382.432
x = 36000.000 y = 6000.000 57714359.227
x = 42000.000 y = 6000.000 51344053.014
x = 48000.000 y = 6000.000 46504195.328
x = 54000.000 y = 6000.000 42645485.184
x = 60000.000 y = 6000.000 39383135.045
x = 66000.000 y = 6000.000 36503601.927
x = 72000.000 y = 6000.000 33906397.885
x = 78000.000 y = 6000.000 31549562.790
x = 84000.000 y = 6000.000 29413881.406
x = 90000.000 y = 6000.000 27485022.692
x = 96000.000 y = 6000.000 25747308.814
x = 102000.000 y = 6000.000 24183060.392
x = 108000.000 y = 6000.000 22773771.758
x = 114000.000 y = 6000.000 21501411.342
x = 120000.000 y = 6000.000 20349309.589

x = 0.000 y = 0.000 Infinity
x = 6000.000 y = 0.000 100727887.297
x = 12000.000 y = 0.000 73761352.315
x = 18000.000 y = 0.000 66212943.818
x = 24000.000 y = 0.000 61270265.934
x = 30000.000 y = 0.000 56077317.023
x = 36000.000 y = 0.000 50954258.363
x = 42000.000 y = 0.000 46446801.595
x = 48000.000 y = 0.000 42653517.292
x = 54000.000 y = 0.000 39443591.760
x = 60000.000 y = 0.000 36657581.022
x = 66000.000 y = 0.000 34177763.559
x = 72000.000 y = 0.000 31933712.779
x = 78000.000 y = 0.000 29887773.362
x = 84000.000 y = 0.000 28019549.163
x = 90000.000 y = 0.000 26315443.395
x = 96000.000 y = 0.000 24763403.028
x = 102000.000 y = 0.000 23351100.207
x = 108000.000 y = 0.000 22065812.711
x = 114000.000 y = 0.000 20894889.957
x = 120000.000 y = 0.000 19826260.654
```

been trying to find the problem for 2-3 hours straight to no prevail

Comment: to: sweber
ive tried all the options you presented to me but to no prevail.
ive type in the command pwd and moved the data file into the working directories.
and ive edited my java program so it now gives 3 colums data, but i still get the same error message.
please help, is windows 8 a problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You habe two problems.

> warning: Skipping unreadable file "potentialsurface03"

This means gnuplot could not open the file, e.g. because you misspelled the filename **or** because the file simply is not found. This might be because the current working directory is not the same as where the data is. You can get the current working directory by the command `pwd` in gnuplot to test this. Three solutions:

- use the command `cd 'C:\path\to\my\data'` to navigate to the directory containing the data file (The `\` makes trouble when using double quotes `" "`, so use single quotes `' '`!. Alternative: Use `/` instead of `\`)
- Write all commands to a text file next to your data file, and open this file with gnuplot (right-click, open with, ...). In this case, the working directory automatically is the one containing the text file.
- use `splot 'C:\path\to\my\data\potentialsurface03'` which is ugly

The second problem you are not yet aware of:

Your data file contains seven colums:

```
x = 0.000 y = 120000.000 19826260.654
1 2 3     4 5 6          7
```

*Note: Columns are separated by spaces or tabs, multiple of this characters are concatenated*

The command `splot` needs three columns, if you don't specify them, it uses columns 1, 2, 3 for x, y, z. As you can see, it will try to read the characters `x` and `=` as values for x and y, which will of course fail and give you another error message. Use

```
splot "potentialsurface03" using 3:6:7
```

to read the values from the correct columns

Comment: thanks ive finally got it, it seems like i have to have a space before the first data for it to work